# Command to start launcher's app drawer view using android manager?

Tags: android, adb, launcher, cyanogenmod

I opened up the app drawer on my phone and used `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` to collect the information about the current activity and used that in the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME -f 0x10600000 -n com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/.Launcher
```

However, this does not start the launcher's app drawer, it just starts the launcher.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to use the command line to open the app drawer on my phone?

By the way, I am running Cyanogenmod 10.1.2-maguro.

Comment: I quickly looked at the [source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Trebuchet/blob/cm-10.1.2/AndroidManifest.xml) of Trebuchet (CyanogenMod's Launcher), there is no "drawer activity" to start. I don't know if there exists another method to open the drawer than starting an activity, but it seems impossible to me.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem possible to call the method to open the drawer from a shell script :/

Answer (score 1):

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet

Comment: Doesn't help in launching app drawer. It just brings you back to home screen.